# Derive the queries compatible to oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to derive these queries compatible to Oracle.could you suggest how all these queries to write in one single query.

```
delete from need_status_history   
JOIN need_entl ON  need_status_history.need_entl_puid= need_entl.need_entl_puid    
where need_entl.user_guid=x;


delete  from need_entl_order_history    
JOIN need_entl ON need_entl_order_history.need_entl_puid = need_entl.need_entl_puid    
where need_entl.user_guid=x;


delete from need_entl_notif_history    
JOIN need_entl ON need_entl_notif_history.need_entl_puid=need_entl.need_entl_puid
where need_entl.user_guid=x;


delete from need_entl where user_guid= x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it goes.

In Oracle, you can't use such a syntax (except for the last `delete` you wrote). The simplest & probably the most straightforward query would be something like this:

```
delete from need_status_history h
where h.need_entl_puid in (select e.need_entl_puid
                           from need_entl e
                           where e.user_guid = 'x'
                          );
```

As of your idea to use a single query for 4 deletes - well, that won't happen either. Not unless you put all of them into a stored procedure (or an anonymous PL/SQL block) and run it as such.

---

Based on your comment, it seems you don't quite believe what I'm saying so - here's an example:

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table need_status_history (need_entl_puid number);

Table created.

SQL> create table need_entl (user_guid varchar2(10), need_entl_puid number);

Table created.
```

Your query:

```
SQL> delete from need_status_history
  2  JOIN need_entl ON  need_status_history.need_entl_puid= need_entl.need_entl_puid
  3  where need_entl.user_guid='x';
JOIN need_entl ON  need_status_history.need_entl_puid= need_entl.need_entl_puid
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Suggested query:

```
SQL> delete from need_status_history h
  2  where h.need_entl_puid in (select e.need_entl_puid
  3                             from need_entl e
  4                             where e.user_guid = 'x'
  5                            );

0 rows deleted.

SQL>
```

Convinced?

Comment: You're saying above all queries syntax wrong. we can't write queries like those

Comment: No; I said all but one are wrong. I edited my answer and added some more info. Have a look, please.

Comment: Ok got it, But why only one query wrong in all those when i run in my data base it's working fine.

Comment: Which database do you use? I mean, the one where your queries work OK?

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a **tool** used to access a database. I asked which **database** you use. Because, queries you wrote won't work with Oracle (database).

Comment: It seems we don't understand each other. I'll try once again: when you wrote a question, you posted several `delete` statements. They won't work in an Oracle database. I told you what to do. I posted an example which shows that your queries won't work (except the last one). Reading your comments, I thought that your background might be something else (e.g. MS SQL Sever or DB2 or ...), i.e. a database where `delete` statements you wrote work, and now  you want to "translate" them to Oracle.

Comment: if i want retrieve data using select  same query how i will write query  in oracle. can you explain

Comment: Using a `select` statement. Oracle's syntax is very rich, can be very complex, but - in its simple appearance, it can be e.g. `select empno, ename, job from emp where deptno = 10`, i.e. return some columns from the `emp` table where department number equals `10`.

Comment: If those tables and columns exist, yes - looks like a properly written query.

Comment: Yes tables and columns exist, Thank you

Comment: No problem :) I'm glad if I helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one DELETE statement - but you're going to need to write some other statements first. :-)

It appears that all of your tables are related to the `NEED_ENTL` by the `NEED_ENTL_PUID` field. I'm assuming here the on the `NEED_ENTL` table, the `NEED_ENTL_PUID` field is either the primary key or is a unique key. What you should do is set up foreign key constraints on each of your sub-tables which refer back to the `NEED_ENTL` table, such that when you delete a row from `NEED_ENTL` all the rows in the sub-tables (`NEED_STATUS_HISTORY`, `NEED_ENTL_ORDER_HISTORY`, and `NEED_ENTL_NOTIF_HISTORY`) are automatically deleted. Something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE NEED_STATUS_HISTORY
  ADD CONSTRAINT NEED_STATUS_HISTORY_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (NEED_ENTL_PUID) REFERENCES NEED_ENTL (NEED_ENTL_PUID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE NEED_ENTL_ORDER_HISTORY
  ADD CONSTRAINT NEED_ENTL_ORDER_HISTORY_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (NEED_ENTL_PUID) REFERENCES NEED_ENTL (NEED_ENTL_PUID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE NEED_ENTL_NOTIF_HISTORY
  ADD CONSTRAINT NEED_ENTL_NOTIF_HISTORY_FK1
    FOREIGN KEY (NEED_ENTL_PUID) REFERENCES NEED_ENTL (NEED_ENTL_PUID)
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then when you issue your `DELETE` command:

```
DELETE FROM NEED_ENTL
  WHERE USER_GUID = X;
```

all of the rows in `NEED_STATUS_HISTORY`, `NEED_ENTL_ORDER_HISTORY`, and `NEED_ENTL_NOTIF_HISTORY` which are related to the row(s) you deleted from `NEED_ENTL` will automatically be deleted without your having to do anything else.